# How to read column names 'as is' from CSV file?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file containing some columns with names like `"beauty & spas"`, `"american (new)"` etc. When I read this file in R and use `names()` to see column names, they have been converted to `"beauty...spas.1"` and `"american...new..1"`. How do I prevent them from being converted? I do not want to correct them manually.

Answer (score 14):

If you read the documentation carefully at `?read.table` (or `?read.csv`) you will quickly see that there is an argument called `check.names`. You most likely want to set that to `FALSE`. Keep in mind, though, that those are not syntactically valid column names in R, so you you might actually prefer to change them to something that R will handle more smoothly anyway.

Comment: Thank you for replying instantly. Great help.

Comment: What joran is saying is that you can do `data$thing` to get a column but you have to quote it if it has a 'syntactically invalid' name: `data$"beauty & spas"` which is a bit awkward... Note you can always do something like `read.csv("test.csv",nrows=1, head=FALSE)` to just read the first line of a file to get the column headers.

Comment: (Also, if Joran has answered your question, click the little tick mark!)