# R load CSV with # in headers

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to load a csv file that has symbol '#' in the header. This is causing an error message 'More Columns than Column Names'. I've followed some the articles ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028093/r-programming-more-columns-than-column-names) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010108/how-to-read-column-names-as-is-from-csv-file)), but I can not manage to sort it out.

The problem seems to be that the upload excludes columns after the #. For example, I've created a file with the following column headers (no rows)

```
A   B#  C # D
```

When I upload I get the following:

```
hTest <- read.table("C:/Users/xxx/headerTest.csv",header=T, sep = ',',check.names=FALSE)
hTest
[1] A B
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

As you can see, after the # in column B the following columns are ignored

Any ideas on how to resolve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried treating column names as 1st row? doing header = F, and col classes all as character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `comment.char = ''`

```
df1 <- read.table("temp.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", comment.char = '')
```

You will get a `.` in place of `#`. After reading the file contents, you can edit the column names using `colnames()` function.